# How to prevent smart diagram from hyphenating?

Tags: hyphenation, smartdiagram

In a descriptive diagram, how do I prevent smart diagram from hyphenating texts when there are two more lines? Adding `\raggedright` does not work for me.

A minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
    \smartdiagramset{description title text width=1.5cm,
    description text width=7cm,description width=8cm}
    \smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
      {x,the contribution to the projection Xxxxxxxxx Xxxxx}}

\end{document}
```

Note that technically I can change the width to be really wide, but it's too troubling when there are too many long descriptions...

Comment: *within the local group for the command*, add `\hyphenpenalty10000 \exhyphenpenalty10000`. these are the settings to suppress hyphenation using the primitive attributes that govern hyphenation of ordinary words and words that already contain hyphens, respectively.  when you exit the group, the values are automatically restored to the usual for the body text.

Comment: The problem is that `smardiagram` uses `align=center` in the nodes, but doesn't seem to have any option for changing it to `align=flush center` (which would avoid hyphenation).

Comment: @egreg Interesting. Maybe we can ask whether the author is willing to add such an option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the simplest method for suppressing hyphenation within a group is this:

*within the local group for the command*, add

```
\hyphenpenalty10000
\exhyphenpenalty10000
```

these are the settings to suppress hyphenation using the primitive attributes that govern hyphenation of ordinary words and words that already contain hyphens, respectively. when you exit the group, the values are automatically restored to the usual for the body text.

Answer (score 4):

A quick workaround is to use command `\mbox{not hyphenated}`, because this command does not allow an hyphenation of included word(s).

Or you can use `\\` to force a newline inside the description.

Or you can use command `\hyphenation{...}` to force that the listed word(s) is/are not hyphenated in the **complete** document. The word `Donaudampfschifffahrt` is a long german word I used to show the effect ...

Please see the following MWE (see marking `<======`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\hyphenation{Donaudampfschifffahrt}% <==================================
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{description title text width=1.5cm,
  description text width=7cm,description width=8cm}
\smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
  {x,the contribution to the \mbox{projection} Xxxxxxxxx Xxxxx}% <==============
}

\smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
  {x,the contribution to the projection\\ Xxxxxxxxx Xxxxx}% <==============
}

\smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
  {x,the contribution to the Donaudampfschifffahrt\\ Xxxxxxxxx Xxxxx}% <==============
}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: result of mwe above]

Comment: Is it possible to automatically add mbox to all words?

Comment: I believe that a comma should replace your added `% <====`

Comment: `\smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{{x,abc def},}` You can, of course, use end-of-lines like in your answers, but the documentation advises to use a trailing comma.