# Color of a diagram

Tags: color, smartdiagram

I have a question about this diagram:
[How to prevent smart diagram from hyphenating?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304357/how-to-prevent-smart-diagram-from-hyphenating?rq=1)
Is it possible to change the color for this diagram?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!! Specifically what colors do you want to change? I think you should not ask this as a question but in comments on that given answer.

Comment: Hi and welcome. The question you indicate does not specify a color. Do you mean one of the answers? And if so, which one?

Answer (score 1):

Color can be set with the help of

```
\smartdiagramset{set color list={blue!50,red!50,green!50,orange!50!red},}
```

[image]

### The MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{
  set color list={blue!50,red!50,green!50,orange!50!red},
}
\smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
{Set up,The set up operation consist of..},
{Run, {After having set up the program, you must run..}},
{Analyse, You must check what did with analytical tools like..},
{Modify, {After the analysis, you can still modify or add..}},
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would be nice to quote the manual if you copy text verbatim from it